Why does my normal map have yellow values
I'm trying to figure out how to bake normal maps (beginner to Blender and 3d modeling). I made this high-poly and low-poly version of ramen bowls based on this post.
The process I'm following for baking is as follows

UV unwrap the low-poly model
Make sure the two models are overlapped
Render Engine → Cycles
Baking Type → Normal, Space → Tangent, Selected to Active

However, the resulting normal map has these yellow values. It looks like this usually means the normals are reversed? I tried to check the face orientation of my models but didn't see any red faces indicating so. The render tab also shows the low-poly bowl as having this black color

Not sure if it's because my low-poly model is kind of poking out of the high-poly one?

I tried to use a Cage object as some other posts have suggested. But that didn't really do anything. Would appreciate any help!
Edit: Here is my updated blend file 

Hello, you may need to increase the Extrusion value a bit, but maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com

I would recommend reading and learning everything these two posts 1 2. For help understanding issues when baking normal maps.

So from my understanding of the posts, the main reason the normal map is coming out weird is due to geometry? Specifically, my low-poly bowl's curvature is very different from the high-poly one, so it'll be very hard to match unless I add more geometry. In terms of solution, I'm thinking of adding more loop cuts to basically make the curvature match closer to the high-poly ver. Is that the right way to go? Also, I see I have normals that are 90 deg to each other, would adding bevels help? https://imgur.com/a/SCjSDgk

I can't see the high-poly in the file you share

@moonboots it's the object named Bowl in the hierarchy https://imgur.com/a/XnQEaPM

@Jakemoyo so I tried to add more geometry to make the low-poly less boxy in a way (the curves on the top rim really stands out currently) and to help get a better normal map bake. I added bevels, and adjusted my seams so the UV unwrapping is better. The result looks a little nicer, but I want to smooth out the rim further. I'm thinking of adding loop cuts, but not sure how to proceed from there. Do you have any advice here? https://imgur.com/a/eIvG5HT

@moonboots just updated the blend file. High-poly should still be the Bowl object, lmk if you still can't see it!

ok but Bowl doesn't have any detail to bake so I'm not sure why you are trying to bake it?

I think this actually answers one of my questions, namely do I even need to bake. I was assuming that it’ll magically transform a low-poly and make it look like a high-poly, but I guess that’s not the case. One thing I was confused by was this low-poly bowl asset I was using (from the Unity store), has only about 460 tris, but they have a normal map, ao map, and rgh that made the asset look really good in Unity (even tho it’s just a plain white bowl). Do you know how they achieved it? https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/props/interior/plates-bowls-mugs-pack-146682

I don't know but we can clearly see the angles, the bowls are not very smooth, but yes you can't make the silhouette of low-poly look high-poly with a normal map, a normal map will just add details
